# c# asp.net - inserting data into database( dont knw where iam goin wrong)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, database

c# asp.net - inserting data into database( dont knw where iam goin wrong) - this code is executing but not working at all ! i tried to feed data through the website i created but it wont reflect it in my database at all plz help !!!!

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page

{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GARGI-PC\\ROOT;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
    protected void page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}

    public void refress()
    {

        comment1.Text = "";

        software1.Checked = true;

        hardware1.Checked = false;

        both1.Checked = false;

        others.Checked = false;
    }
    protected void btn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string type = string.Empty ;

        if (hardware1.Checked == true)
        {
            type =  "hardware";
        }
         if (software1.Checked == true)
        {
            type = "software";
        }
         if (both1.Checked == true)
        {
            type = "both";
        }
         if (others.Checked == true)
        {
            type = "others";
        }



        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into main_page (type, discription,time) values('" + type + "','" + comment1.Text + "','" + "','"+"now()')", con);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        try

        {

            con.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();

            refress();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        { 

        }

    }

   public void btn_clear(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        refress();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have a double comma in your `INSERT` statement.

```
+ "','" + "','"
```

The `INSERT` statement should look like:

```
INSERT INTO main_page (type, description, time) VALUES ('Type', 'Description', NOW())
```

Also you are vulnerable to SQL injection, you should [paramerterize your queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html) for **all** of your inputs rather than trusting the data from your users. As a basic example:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO main_page (Description) VALUES @Description");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", comment1.Text);
```

This would protect you if a user entered a SQL statement within the Comment1 textbox.

```
ArbitaryData; DROP TABLE main_page;
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should use the command parameters.  Here, try this as an example:

```
public static void AddSong(Songs s)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(SQL_getConnectionString.conStr()))
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
            try
            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO Songs VALUES(@Id, @Name, @Artist, @Album, @TrackNumber, @TrackNumberCount, " +
                    "@Genre, @Rating, @Tags, @Subject, @Categories, @Comments, @FileName, @FolderName, @FolderPath, " +
                    "@FullPath, @Length, @PlayCount, @SkipCount, @LastPlayed)";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = s.Id;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = s.Name;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Album", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = s.Album;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Artist", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = s.Artist;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TrackNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = s.TrackNumber;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TrackNumberCount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = s.TrackNumberCount;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Genre", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = s.Genre;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Rating", SqlDbType.Int).Value = s.Rating;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tags", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = s.Tags;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Subject", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = s.Subject;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Categories", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = s.Categories;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Comments", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = s.Comments;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = s.FileName;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FolderName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = s.FolderName;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FolderPath", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = s.FolderPath;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FullPath", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = s.FullPath;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Length", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = s.Length;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PlayCount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = s.PlayCount;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SkipCount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = s.SkipCount;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastPlayed", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = s.LastPlayed;

                    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlcon.Close();

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not insert. {0}", s.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Error Message {0}", ex.Message);
            }


        }
    }
```